# what is the best way to name JS projects files and directories?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a reactjs project with typescript. Should the ts class filename start with uppercase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the project and if it's an existing project (in which case you usually follow the existing standard).
Usually Components files will be uppercased, like List.tsx, function files will be lowerCase, like addNumbers.ts or utils.ts, and Folders upper cased, like Navbar.

Have a look here for more info https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html

Answer (score 3):

Any way is fine as long as it's consistent. Personally, I prefer kebab-case (file-name.ts) for both folders and files.